# xml node and other info inside node

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have a simple xml file with nodes and some other info. And i want to pull out the index from the series node.

XML:

```
  <record>
    <id>5055</id>
    <uuid>83885ffc-93d8-41ba-aee2-e5c0ae48fc68</uuid>
    <publisher>Now Comics</publisher>
    <size>5803436</size>
    <title sort="Terminator - The Burning Earth 5, The">The Terminator - The Burning Earth 5</title>
    <authors sort="Unknown">
      <author>Unknown</author>
    </authors>
    <timestamp>2012-05-13T19:38:03-07:00</timestamp>
    <pubdate>2012-05-13T19:38:03-07:00</pubdate>
    <series index="5.0">The Terminator: The Burning Earth</series>
    <cover>M:/Comics/Unknown/The Terminator - The Burning Earth 5 (5055)/cover.jpg</cover>
    <formats>
      <format>M:/Comics/Unknown/The Terminator - The Burning Earth 5 (5055)/The Terminator - The Burning Earth 5 - Unknown.cbr</format>
    </formats>
  </record>
```

PHP:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
$dom->load($loc);  
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('record') as $e) {

$publisher = $e->getElementsByTagName('publisher')->item(0)->textContent; 
$arc = $e->getElementsByTagName('series')->item(0)->textContent;    
$uuid = $e->getElementsByTagName('uuid')->item(0)->textContent;

}
```

Now in the xml file at `<series index="5.0">The Terminator: The Burning Earth</series>` i want to pull out that `index="5.0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [getAttribute()](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) method.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($loc);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('record') as $e) {

    $publisher = $e->getElementsByTagName('publisher')->item(0)->textContent;
    $uuid = $e->getElementsByTagName('uuid')->item(0)->textContent;

    $series = $e->getElementsByTagName('series')->item(0);
    $series_index = $series->getAttribute('index');
    $arc = $series->textContent;
}

echo 'Publisher: '.$publisher.'<br />', //Now Comics
     'UUID: '.$uuid.'<br />', //UUID: 83885ffc-93d8-41ba-aee2-e5c0ae48fc68
     'Index: '.$series_index.'<br />', //Index: 5.0
     'Title: '.$arc.'<hr />'; //Title: The Terminator: The Burning Earth
```

Comment: Thank You! Forgot about that.

Comment: No probs, one thing i see is that if your not echoing or creating an array for later use, having more then one `record` will just be replaced by the previous iteration, I only added echo as an example. :)